# How to use on-key function in Racket?

Tags: racket

I am trying to make a door simulator. By using keys, I can change the state of door, I looked at the documentation in Racket. It mainly talks about some common keys like "up" "down" "left" "right". I wanna ask how can I customize the keys. Here are my codes:

```
(define DOOR-OPEN-iamge)

(define DOOR-CLOSED-image)

(define DOOR-LOCKED-image)

(define DS-OPEN "open")

(define DS-CLOSED "closed")

(define DS-LOCKED "locked")



(define (door-simulator initial-ds)

  (big-bang initial-ds

    [to-draw draw-ds]
 
   [on-key change]))

(check-expect (draw-ds DS-OPEN) DOOR-OPEN)

(check-expect (draw-ds DS-CLOSED) DOOR-CLOSED)

(check-expect (draw-ds DS-LOCKED) DOOR-LOCKED)

(define (draw-ds ds)

  (cond

    [(string=? ds DS-OPEN) DOOR-OPEN]

    [(string=? ds DS-CLOSED) DOOR-CLOSED]

    [(string=? ds DS-LOCKED) DOOR-LOCKED]))
```

;key for door state

;"o"-DOOR-CLOSED => DOOR-OPEN

;"c"-DOOR-OPEN => DOOR-CLOSED

;"l"-DOOR-CLOSED => DOOR-LOCKED

;"u"-DOOR-LOCKED => DOOR-OPEN

```
(check-expect (change DOOR-CLOSED) DOOR-OPEN)

(check-expect (change DOOR-OPEN) DOOR-CLOSED)

(check-expect (change DOOR-CLOSED) DOOR-LOCKED)

(check-expect (change DOOR-LOCKED) DOOR-OPEN)

(define (change w a-key)

  (cond

    [(key=? a-key "o")  (draw-ds w)]

    [(key=? a-key "c") (draw-ds w)]

    [(key=? a-key "l")    (draw-ds w)]

    [(key=? a-key "u")  (draw-ds w)]))
```

Also, the key part's check-expect didn't work. What functions or variables I should use for that part though.

Comment: `change` takes WorldState and KeyEvent (ie String) arguments and produces a WorldState (a "`DS-`" value). So `change` doesn't call `draw-ds` (only `big-bang` calls `draw-ds`). The check-expects for change are like: `(check-expect (change DS-CLOSED "o") DS-OPEN)`

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow's code formatting and you don't need all those blank lines. Thjis will make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require these libraries ([`planetcute`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpPlanet_Cute_Images.html) just contains some pictures for drawing, you can remove it later):

```
(require 2htdp/planetcute)
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)
```

The first six definitions won't change, I just added some images from `planetcute`:

```
(define door-open chest-open)
(define door-closed chest-closed)
(define door-locked chest-lid)

(define ds-open "open")
(define ds-closed "closed")
(define ds-locked "locked")
```

Definition of `door-simulator` won't change:

```
(define (door-simulator initial-ds)
  (big-bang initial-ds
    [to-draw draw-ds]
    [on-key change]))
```

`draw-ds` converts state to picture and draws it to background with [`place-image`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._place-image%29%29):

```
(define (ds->image ds)
  (cond ((string=? ds ds-open) door-open)
        ((string=? ds ds-closed) door-closed)
        ((string=? ds ds-locked) door-locked)
        (#true door-open)))

(define bg (rectangle 500 500 "solid" "white"))

(define (draw-ds state)
  (place-image (ds->image state)  50 50 bg))
```

Function `change` won't call `draw-ds`, but just returns new state, based on current state and key:

```
(define (change state a-key)
  (cond
    [(and (key=? a-key "o")
          (string=? state ds-closed))
     ds-open]
    [(and (key=? a-key "c")
          (string=? state ds-open))
     ds-closed]
    [(and (key=? a-key "l")
           (string=? state ds-closed))
     ds-locked]
    [(and (key=? a-key "u")
          (string=? state ds-locked)) ds-open]
    (#true state)))
```

You might need to reorder these definitions, then start animation with `(door-simulator ds-closed)` and press some keys (`o`, `c`...).